# Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

I was able to run the my AVD shown below successfully.
[avd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBQQc.png)

However after a couple of API updates and update of the Android Studio to 3.0, I'm unable to run the AVD successfully again. Keep getting the error below:
[avd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwcsY.png)

My AVD is also super slow and i am running a windows PC with 8GB RAM.

Below is the details of my avd.

```
Name: Pixel_API_25

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Blah\.android\avd\Pixel_API_25.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 25)

Skin: pixel

SD Card: 100 MiB

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 25

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Pixel_API_25

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 480

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel API 25

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:524882cfa9f421413193056700a29392

hw.ramSize: 1024

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.sdCard: no

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should uninstall the **HAXM** and reinstall it, make sure to allocate at least 2 GB of ram to it. and when you create your emulated device give it less then you gave to the **HAXM** i'd say 1 GB that should speed things up . but i wold suggest you more RAM 8 GB is low. My system is using 10 GB with Google Chrome, Android Studio and emulator open. When going to a new version you should also go to **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Comment: Thanks for your response Mihai. I tried this out but i wasn't presented with a field  to allocate the 2GB of RAM in Intel HAXM installer. Am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Just go to **Tools > Android > SDK Manager** then go to **SDK Tools** panel and uncheck **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)** and click apply, this will uninstall it. To install it again once the uninstall process finishes just check the box and click apply it should prompt you to select the memory just read the prompts before clicking next it will be the second prompt if i recall correctly .

Comment: One more thing while in the **SDK Manager** make sure to update the API's for the level you are using in the emulator click the **SDK Platforms** panel all the ones that need updating will show up there.

Comment: Thanks for you response Mihai. I tried all you specified above but am still getting the same error.Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Android studio 3.0.1, tried to follow above but didn't work.

Strangely changing the Target from "Open Select Deployment Target Dialog" to "Emulator" in "Run/Debug Configurations" fixed this problem.

Test app has been installed. After successful installation, I have reverted back the Target still works.

Answer (score 0):

May be your h/w acceleration is disabled. You should try enabling h/w acceleration through BIOS. This might help with slow speed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an answer. Please finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a stabile internet connection with your preferred Proxy settings. My corporate proxy settings caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

Wiping data for your virtual device might also do the trick (Wipe data from Actions dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning Android Studio Project and Restarting the Emulator helped me.